# Highchart download issue in safari

Tags: html, css, highcharts, safari

I am facing one issue in highcharts . I have a site which is using highchart. In download options png, jpeg, pdf and svg  are working but `Download CSV` and `Download XLS` are not working in safari.
 I am using normal highchart [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/alfinpaul/pycgjh71/).

Any advice?
Any Solution?

[image]

Comment: Tested on Safari 11.1.2 with your demo. No problems. Any more details?

Comment: Tested on Version 11.1.2 (13605.3.8) too, and everything is fine. Please tell us what version of browser and OSX are you using?

Comment: omg! my desktop safai Version 9.1.1(11601.6.17), OS X Version 10.11.5